# Can't register my custom AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to make a very simple spring-mvc application with embedded tomcat. I thought that `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` was registered automatically but I have read some things saying the contrary. So, I tried also marking the `Main` class as `@Configuration` and adding a function to retrieve a Bean of that type.

I expected to get views from MEB-INF/views and with ".jsp" suffix instead of from the templates directory and ".html" suffix. I also wanted to change the application context.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}


//second Main option I mentioned
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring")
@Configuration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer webAppInitializer(){
        return new MyWebAppInitializer();
    }
}

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}

@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(path={"/"},method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message","Hello Spring MVC!");

        //Java 8 LocalDate
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        model.addAttribute("date", date.format(formatter));

        return "index";
    }
}
```

[The view directory layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQDo9.png)

`application.properties` is empty. It is there because I was trying all sorts of configurations.

Startup trace

```
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)
2018-03-04 19:43:47.211  INFO 1987 --- [           main] com.boraji.tutorial.spring.Main          : Starting Main v1.0-SNAPSHOT on javier-N56VZ with PID 1987 (/home/javier/test_src/springtest2/target/spring-test-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by javier in /home/javier/test_src/springtest2)

2018-03-04 19:43:47.215  INFO 1987 --- [           main] com.boraji.tutorial.spring.Main          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2018-03-04 19:43:47.549  INFO 1987 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@30946e09: startup date [Sun Mar 04 19:43:47 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy

2018-03-04 19:43:48.880  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2018-03-04 19:43:48.892  INFO 1987 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2018-03-04 19:43:48.893  INFO 1987 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27

2018-03-04 19:43:48.974  INFO 1987 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2018-03-04 19:43:48.974  INFO 1987 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1429 ms

2018-03-04 19:43:49.055  INFO 1987 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]

2018-03-04 19:43:49.059  INFO 1987 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]

2018-03-04 19:43:49.179  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controllers.HelloWorldController.sayHello(org.springframework.ui.Model)

2018-03-04 19:43:49.180  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/bye]}" onto public java.lang.String com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controllers.ByeController.bye()

2018-03-04 19:43:49.188  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

2018-03-04 19:43:49.188  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

2018-03-04 19:43:49.218  INFO 1987 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]

2018-03-04 19:43:49.256  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@30946e09: startup date [Sun Mar 04 19:43:47 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy

2018-03-04 19:43:50.113  INFO 1987 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup

2018-03-04 19:43:50.180  INFO 1987 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)

2018-03-04 19:43:50.186  INFO 1987 --- [           main] com.boraji.tutorial.spring.Main          : Started Main in 3.308 seconds (JVM running for 3.697)
```

=== POM ===

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL Dependency-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- JSP Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot you don't need to extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, that is only for plain Spring applications. Basically you are making things overly complex with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your application.properties under resources but not WEB-INF. Also, would be nice to have error stack trace.

Comment: application.properties is really empty. I was just trying stuff to make it work. I have added the pom and the startup trace. There isn't any error trace because the controller is executed but the view for "welcome" is being taken as "templates/welcome.html".

Answer (score 0):

First off all I would strongly suggest **not** to use JSP as your view layer but something like [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org). When using JSP with Spring Boot there are [certain limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) that you have to take into consideration.

That being said you are making things overly complex. To make it work.

1. Remove the `RootConfig` class
2. Remove the `WebConfig` class
3. Remove the `MyWebAppInitializer`
4. Remove the `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` from the `Main` class
5. Move your `Main` class to `com.boraji.tutorial`
6. Remove the plain `org.springframework` dependencies from your `pom.xml` and use the `spring-boot-starter-web` instead
7. Remove the `maven-compiler-plugin`
8. Add the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency as a `provided` one
9. Add `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` to the `application.properties`

Basically this reduces your `Main` class to something like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

And your dependencies to something like this

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Make also sure that you use `<packaging>war</packaging>` as a type for your pom and instead of the `maven-compiler-plugin` use the `<properties>` section to set the java version.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Finally add the `suffix` and `prefix` to your `application.properties`.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Now this will also make your application JSP only (although you still have the Thymeleaf dependency in your list of dependencies).

For more inspiration (or missing dependencies) you might want to take a look at the [JSP Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) from Spring Boot.